# Datasheet for this processor(M3329 CPU (MIPS architecture))

Tags: datasheet, processor

Where can i find datasheet for this processor?
Look:

[image: processor]

Also, I could found some information of this link: [Acer Laboratories Incorporated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_Laboratories_Incorporated) but it's not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to, ALi only supplies datasheets to their product integrators, and only if you buy in significant volume. Furthermore, they don't exist anymore as ALi (ALi chips are Nvidia-branded now) and especially obsolete products like this are likely completely unsupported.

You will have to find somebody or some company that has worked with this chip who is willing to give you datasheets from their engineering stash or something.