# How do I operate a tuner of digital satellite receiver using a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, receiver, processor, tv

I want to operate this tuner of my digital satellite receiver.
This is the tuner:

[image: receiver]

[image: tuner]

[image: tuner]

They wrote some numbers and words around of the tuner:

[image: N-W]

[image: N-W]

and the name and model of the receiver is "DigiStar D600 Digital Satellite Receiver".

What MCU or processor is suitable for operating it?
Where can I find information for operating this?
I couldn't find any datasheet.

i seperated the tuner from the pcb and toke two picture, look(i hope these two picture help me for get answer):

[image: SE1]

[image: SE2]

Comment: I think that's probably just the analog front-end to the tuner; the large "ALi" IC will contain vital parts of the tuning and decoding process. What do you mean by "operate", anyway?

Comment: @pjc50 for "ALI" you can see the answer in this link: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82553/datasheet-for-this-processorm3329-cpu-mips-architecture

Comment: my mean(for operate) is, the use of it

Comment: From the look of the two orange capacitors above (and on the right) the power transformer, you had better finish your project soon.

Comment: @Joe Hass How? Do you want that i take several picture of that side?

Comment: You mean you want to change channels or what exactly?

Comment: No, please don't take more photos. A bulging electrolytic capacitor indicates a higher probability of failure. Your board appears to be 5 or 6 years old so that's not unusual, but those capacitors may fail sooner rather than later.

Comment: i added two picture of inside the tuner.

Comment: If you can't find a datasheet for that part, it will take a great deal of effort to try to investigate what it does and how it's interface works. For people like me it would be impossible, especially after removing it from a working motherboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would get an extra remote control for the receiver, and mount it in such a way that it sits on top of receiver, and shines down on the IR window of the receiver (perhaps using a mirror).

Then hack into the remote control, and wire into the buttons that you need to operate the receiver.

The easiest way to do this, without trying to figure out the input circuit of the remote, is to wire reed relays across the contacts (note that the buttons probably don't actually have contacts in themselves, but may operate dome switches or some other type of switch contact located on the PCB of the remote controller).

If you want to get fancier, and use less relays, you will probably find that the conact switches are arranged in some sort of array (for example, 6x6 would use 12 wires, but would allow for 36 buttons).  So then you just have to control the appropriate two wires for each button.

In either case, I would attach a couple of wires to a single button first (such as Mute), and try connecting them manually and observing the result.

Beside reed relays, it would probably be possible to go all solid state using FETs, but you would need to reverse engineer more of the circuit.

Comment: While @tcrosley answer is a good avenue to look into, it's way more complicated than needed. You don't even need a second control, or relays or anything. Most standard remote controls can be emulated in software. Arduino, msp430 launchpads, any modern microcontroller can do it quite easily. But that said, it seems like OP might be looking into directly accessing the tuner, not the entire receiver. OP hasn't really clarified.

Comment: as @Passerby said, i want to directly accessing the tuner, not the entire receiver. i want to find the name and usage of tuner's pins. i think that IC is a synthesiser at the tuner.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the last place you would look for such information: [**the Linux kernel source code**](https://www.kernel.org/). You won't find the datasheet, but you will find the source code of a driver for a DVB card with the same tuner. The same IC can be found in the [STB6000](http://git.linuxtv.org/cgit.cgi/media_tree.git/tree/drivers/media/dvb-frontends/stb6000.c) tuner. You just have to adapt the code.

The code I will provide is adapted from `ix2476.c` and `ix2476.h` which I cannot find online now - they were in older Linux kernels.

The following pseudo-code is just an adaptation of the original code `Copyright (C) 2008 Igor M. Liplianin (liplianin@me.by)` and follows the same license `GNU GPL v2`. I only removed specific kernel routines and rewrote the I2C communication routines.

```
#define IX2476_XTAL_KHZ     (4000) // Replace accordingly
#define IX2476_PLL_STEP     (IX2476_XTAL_KHZ / 8)

unsigned char by1, by2, by3, by4;

unsigned long int ix2476_calculate_pll_lpf_cutoff(unsigned long int baud) // PRIVATE
{
    if (baud >= 39000000)                          return 30000; //LPF=30MHz
    if ((39000000 > baud) && (baud >= 35000000))   return 28000; //LPF=28MHz
    if ((35000000 > baud) && (baud >= 30000000))   return 26000; //LPF=26MHz
    if ((30000000 > baud) && (baud >= 26000000))   return 24000; //LPF=24MHz
    if ((26000000 > baud) && (baud >= 23000000))   return 22000; //LPF=22MHz
    if ((23000000 > baud) && (baud >= 21000000))   return 20000; //LPF=20MHz
    if ((21000000 > baud) && (baud >= 19000000))   return 18000; //LPF=18MHz
    if ((19000000 > baud) && (baud >= 18000000))   return 16000; //LPF=16MHz
    if ((18000000 > baud) && (baud >= 17000000))   return 14000; //LPF=14MHz
    if ((17000000 > baud) && (baud >= 16000000))   return 12000; //LPF=12MHz
    else                                           return 10000; //LPF=10MHz
    return 0;
}

void ix2476_calculate_pll_vco(unsigned long int freq, unsigned long int *div, unsigned long int *ba) // PRIVATE
{
    *div = 1;
    *ba = 6;

    if ((950000 <= freq) && (freq < 1065000))          *div = 1, *ba = 6;
    else if ((1065000 <= freq) && (freq < 1170000))    *div = 1, *ba = 7;
    else if ((1170000 <= freq) && (freq < 1300000))    *div = 0, *ba = 1;
    else if ((1300000 <= freq) && (freq < 1445000))    *div = 0, *ba = 2;
    else if ((1445000 <= freq) && (freq < 1607000))    *div = 0, *ba = 3;
    else if ((1607000 <= freq) && (freq < 1778000))    *div = 0, *ba = 4;
    else if ((1778000 <= freq) && (freq < 1942000))    *div = 0, *ba = 5;
    else if (1942000 <= freq)                          *div = 0, *ba = 6;
}

bool ix2476_isRfLocked() // PUBLIC
{
    /**
    Read 1 byte from address 0xC1. Replace with your code.
    **/
    i2c_start();
    i2c_write(0xC1);
    unsigned char byt = i2c_read(true); // ACK read
    i2c_stop();

    return (byt & 0x40);
}

void ix2476_set_params(unsigned long int freq, unsigned long int sr) // PUBLIC, freq = kHz, sr = kSymb/s (e.g. freq=1090000, sr=27500000)
{
    // Frequency
    unsigned long int data = freq / IX2476_PLL_STEP;
    by1 = (data >> 8) & 0x1F;
    by2 = data;

    // Local oscillator
    unsigned long int div, ba;
    ix2476_calculate_pll_vco(freq, &div, &ba);
    by4 = (ba << 5) | ((div & 1) << 1);

    // LPF Cut-off
    unsigned long int cutoff;
    cutoff = ix2476_calculate_pll_lpf_cutoff(sr);
    cutoff = ((cutoff / 1000) / 2) - 2;
    unsigned long int pd2, pd3, pd4, pd5;
    pd2 = (cutoff >> 1) & 0x04;
    pd3 = (cutoff << 1) & 0x08;
    pd4 = (cutoff << 2) & 0x08;
    pd5 = (cutoff << 4) & 0x10;

    by3 &= 0xE7;
    by3 |= (pd5 | pd4);
    by4 &= 0xF3;
    by4 |= (pd3 | pd2);

    unsigned long int reg2, reg3;
    reg2 = by3;
    reg3 = by4;
    by3 &= 0xE3;
    by4 &= 0xF3;

    /* Write I2C: 0xC0 address followed by all 4 bytes */
    i2c_start();
    i2c_write(0xC0);
    i2c_write(by1);
    i2c_write(by2);
    i2c_write(by3);
    i2c_write(by4);
    i2c_stop();

    by3 |= 0x04;

    waitmsec(10); //optional 10 ms wait

    /* Write I2C: 0xC0 address followed by by3 */
    i2c_start();
    i2c_write(0xC0);
    i2c_write(by3);
    i2c_stop();

    by3 = reg2 | 0x04;
    by4 = reg3;

    waitusec(10); //optional 10 us wait

    /* Write I2C: 0xC0 address followed by 2 bytes */
    i2c_start();
    i2c_write(0xC0);
    i2c_write(by3);
    i2c_write(by4);
    i2c_stop();
}
```

Now all you have to do is find the pinout.